# Simplify class manipulation on elements by using selectors instead of ID targeting

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the example below, how can I generically target *description detail* `<dd>` below its *description term* `<dt>`, and toggle class on targeted `<dd>` and `<button>`, without using IDs.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('button'), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
    e.preventDefault();
   }
   e.target.classList.toggle('active');
  });
 });
 document.getElementById('expand-aluminum').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
    e.preventDefault();
   }
   document.getElementById('aluminum-definition').classList.toggle('open');
 });
 document.getElementById('expand-silver').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
    e.preventDefault();
   }
   document.getElementById('silver-definition').classList.toggle('open');
 });
 document.getElementById('expand-gold').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
    e.preventDefault();
   }
   document.getElementById('gold-definition').classList.toggle('open');
 });
 document.getElementById('expand-platinum').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
    e.preventDefault();
   }
   document.getElementById('platinum-definition').classList.toggle('open');
 });
});
```

```css
dd { visibility: hidden }
.open { visibility: visible }
.active { color: blue }
```

```html
<dl>
<dt>aluminum
<button type=button id=expand-aluminum><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button>
<dd id=aluminum-definition>the chemical element of atomic number 13, a light silvery-grey metal.

<dt>silver
<button type=button id=expand-silver><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button>
<dd id=silver-definition>a precious shiny greyish-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 47.

<dt>gold
<button type=button id=expand-gold><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button>
<dd id=gold-definition>a yellow precious metal, the chemical element of atomic number 79.

<dt>platinum
<button type=button id=expand-platinum><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button>
<dd id=platinum-definition>a precious silvery-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 78.
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding multiple event listeners, you could use event delegation instead, and add a *single* event listener to the `dl`. If the clicked element is a `button`, then navigate to the parent element of the button (the `dt`) and access its `nextElementSibling` to get to the associated `dd`:

```js
document.querySelector('dl').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('button')) return;
  target.classList.toggle('active');
  target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
dd {
  visibility: hidden
}

.open {
  visibility: visible
}

.active {
  color: blue
}

abbr {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>aluminum
<button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>the chemical element of atomic number 13, a light silvery-grey metal.</dd>

  <dt>silver
<button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a precious shiny greyish-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 47.</dd>

  <dt>gold
<button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a yellow precious metal, the chemical element of atomic number 79.</dd>

  <dt>platinum
<button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a precious silvery-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 78.</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thank you.

Two things:
1. The _`i`_ inside the button doesn't turn blue when activated.
2. `dt` and `dd` are elements that have implied end tags – no need to explicitly close them. The HTML is valid. [More info on w3.org.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags)

Comment: Oh, I see. The `tidy` of stack snippets didn't seem to recognize it, so I assumed they needed to be closed. See edit. The blue `i` is very inconspicuous (at least with some fonts), you might consider something else to indicate that the button related to the `dd` is open, maybe color the button slightly differently as well? Just an idea

Comment: One more thing, it looks like with event delegation, the listener won't trigger if you click the *text* of the `i` rather than the surrounding button - you can fix that by giving `pointer-events: none` to `abbr`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you! The blue _`i`_ is just for a simple Stack Overflow example, and it will be visible from space in the production. Great observation about clicking the _`i`_ text rather than the rest of the button area!

Comment: Hey, one more question: what should I add in order for code to work on multiple `dl` on the page. It doesn’t work If I add `querySelectorAll`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Either add the listener to all of them (`document.querySelectorAll('dl').forEach(dl => dl.addEventListener(...`, or use event delegation again, on whatever container contains all the `dl`s `(document.querySelector('body').addEventListener(...`

Comment: Can you help with this one? [Removing class on click from open elements in an accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51941288/7840155)