# Removing class on click from open elements in an accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I keep only one definition visible at the same time in this example:

In other words:

> Clicking on `i` button should toggle class on itself and the
>   definition below the term, and *remove `active` class from other
>   buttons and `open` class from other definitions*.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("dl").forEach(dl =>
  dl.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
    if (!target.matches("button")) return
    target.classList.toggle("active")
    target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("open")
  })
)
```

```css
dd {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0
}

.open {
  visibility: visible;
  height: auto
}

.active {
  color: DeepSkyBlue
}

abbr {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>aluminum
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>the chemical element of atomic number 13, a light silvery-grey metal.</dd>

  <dt>silver
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a precious shiny greyish-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 47.</dd>

  <dt>gold
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a yellow precious metal, the chemical element of atomic number 79.</dd>

  <dt>platinum
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a precious silvery-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 78.</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to hide the open option before opening the new one. You could do like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelectorAll("dl").forEach(dl =>
        dl.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
            if (!target.matches("button")) return
            const dl = target.closest('dl');
            // Check if there is an active button and remove active class
            if (dl.querySelector('.active') != null) {
                dl.querySelector('.active').classList.toggle('active');
            }
            // Check if there is an open dd and close it
            if (dl.querySelector('.open') != null) {
                dl.querySelector('.open').classList.toggle('open');
            }

            target.classList.toggle("active")
            target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("open")
        })
    )
}
```

```css
dd {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0
}

.open {
    visibility: visible;
    height: auto
}

.active {
    color: DeepSkyBlue
}

abbr {
    pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<p>Car List.</p>

<p id="show"></p>
<p id="show1"></p>

<dl>
    <dt>aluminum
    <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
    <dd>the chemical element of atomic number 13, a light silvery-grey metal.</dd>
  
    <dt>silver
    <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
    <dd>a precious shiny greyish-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 47.</dd>
  
    <dt>gold
    <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
    <dd>a yellow precious metal, the chemical element of atomic number 79.</dd>
  
    <dt>platinum
    <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
    <dd>a precious silvery-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 78.</dd>
  </dl>
```

Comment: I have a feeling this could be made more concise.

Comment: Why did you add `window.onload = function()`?

Comment: @Boletrone To wait for the DOM to be ready, if not, the event handlers won't be attached because it won't find the elements in the DOM

Comment: Then why not `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", _ => { }`?

Comment: @Boletrone DOMContentLoaded doesn't work in IE below 9. If you don't have to support IE below version 9, you can use DOMContentLoaded event instead.

Comment: I don’t need anything below `ECMAScript 6`.

Comment: It is not about the ECMAScript version you use, it is about the browsers you want to support. In my opinion, It is fine to go with DOMContentLoaded and don't give support to IE 9, it will load the javascript faster than the `load` event because it does not wait for the resources to be loaded (images, iframes, scripts). It is up to you.

Comment: I know, I was just saying that I would like for the solution to be aligned with the latest methods and practices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178411/discussion-between-boletrone-and-f-cj).

Answer (score 1):

This could be a solution. You can loop through the elements which contain the class you want to toggle, if they do, then toggle it

```js
document.querySelectorAll("dl").forEach(dl =>
  dl.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {

document.querySelectorAll(".open").forEach(function(element) {
    if(element.classList.contains("open")){  
        element.classList.toggle("open");
    }
});

document.querySelectorAll(".active").forEach(function(element) {
    if(element.classList.contains("active")){  
        element.classList.toggle("active");
    }
});

    if (!target.matches("button")) return
    target.classList.toggle("active")
    target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("open")
  })
)
```

```css
dd {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0
}

.open {
  visibility: visible;
  height: auto
}

.active {
  color: DeepSkyBlue
}

abbr {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<body>
<dl>
  <dt>aluminum
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>the chemical element of atomic number 13, a light silvery-grey metal.</dd>

  <dt>silver
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a precious shiny greyish-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 47.</dd>

  <dt>gold
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a yellow precious metal, the chemical element of atomic number 79.</dd>

  <dt>platinum
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a precious silvery-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 78.</dd>
</dl>
</body>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn’t toggle `active` on buttons which remain blue after definition is closed.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same thing but, you don't required to check condition everytime.

You can just use `element.classList="";` to remove all give class from element.

No you don't have "active" and "open" class to any element, you need to use `.classList.add("open")` instead of `.classList.toggle("open")`

Check this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("dl").forEach(dl =>
  dl.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {

document.querySelectorAll("dd").forEach(function(element) {
    element.classList="";
});

document.querySelectorAll(".active").forEach(function(element) {
    element.classList="";
});

    if (!target.matches("button")) return
    target.classList.add("active")
    target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add("open")
  })
)
```

```css
dd {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0
}

.open {
  visibility: visible;
  height: auto
}

.active {
  color: DeepSkyBlue
}

abbr {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>aluminum
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>the chemical element of atomic number 13, a light silvery-grey metal.</dd>

  <dt>silver
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a precious shiny greyish-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 47.</dd>

  <dt>gold
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a yellow precious metal, the chemical element of atomic number 79.</dd>

  <dt>platinum
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a precious silvery-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 78.</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more concise solution which uses only `open` class to do what you need and some CSS & ES6 features.

The idea is to remove `open` to all and then only toggle to the one clicked. Also the entire thing for the removal is chained via ES6 methods.

Also note the `.open+dd` CSS selector since you have siblings and not a container class (it would have been easier with such an approach).

```js
document.querySelectorAll("dl").forEach(dl =>
  dl.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
    if (!target.matches("button")) return
    if (!target.parentElement.classList.contains("open"))
      [...target.parentElement.parentElement.children]
        .filter(({ tagName }) => tagName.toLowerCase() == "dt")
        .forEach(element => element.classList.remove("open"))
    target.parentElement.classList.toggle("open")
  })
)
```

```css
dd {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0
}

.open + dd {
  visibility: visible;
  height: auto
}

.open button {
  color: DeepSkyBlue
}

abbr {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>aluminum
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>the chemical element of atomic number 13, a light silvery-grey metal.</dd>

  <dt>silver
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a precious shiny greyish-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 47.</dd>

  <dt>gold
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a yellow precious metal, the chemical element of atomic number 79.</dd>

  <dt>platinum
  <button type=button><abbr title="See Definition"><i>i</i></abbr></button></dt>
  <dd>a precious silvery-white metal, the chemical element of atomic number 78.</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you! I've made a couple of edits which are in the edit queue.

Comment: Thanks. I think I went too quick on the review and rejected them. Sorry.